# Point Separate Node not working in 2.92 Release Candidate?

Tags: node-editor, geometry, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to separate a point cloud into 2 different outputs using a geometry node and no matter what i try, the point separate mask isn't picking up the attribute, Geometry Output 1 is just showing the output of the ***Group*** vertex group but despite having the mask set up correctly, Geometry Output 2 shows nothing.

I'd like to know what i'm doing wrong or if it's a problem with the Release Candidate.
Thank you.

[image: Output of the Group Vertex Group]

[image: Geometry output 2 shows no points despite the mask having weights that mask out part of the Group vertex group.]

[image: Vertex group for the MASK Vertex group.]

[image: Vertex group for the Group Vertex group.]

Comment: I'm having the very same problem! I was following this video - https://youtu.be/JvBTxd2rRgk?t=1715 and replicated what he was doing precisely, but can't get the mask to show up. It does in the video, however.

Here's my blend file if anyone wants to figure out what the problem is - https://blend-exchange.com/b/OazLgLPg

Comment: Apparently this is still present on the official release that was pushed today, which is worrying. I'm sure i'm using this incorrectly but there's so little info about this and it's rather frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put **Point separate** before **Point distribute**.

After distributing, instances lost geometry data such as Vertex groups.

Comment: Thank you.

Admittedly i hadn't tried this as i've had very limited time to play with these new nodes between work. I believe others are running into this because of a video linked in one of the comments in this thread that sort of served as an introductory guide that was made before a few things were changed.